# How to show actual product price in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have set up WordPress and WooCommerce website but on front-end product prices are different than which I set for product in WooCommerce while creating.

If I set product price **`22.99`**, then on product front-end it shows price of product **`23`**.

Please help me to solve this.

Please find screenshot.
1) Product backend =>
[image]

2) Product frontend =>
[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN1YJ.png

Comment: Thank you Mujeebu Rahman. It works, now able to see actual price after making changes into Number of Decimals option .

Answer (score 0):

> You need to set the **Number of decimals** field in `WooCommerce` >
>   `Settings` > `General`. under Currency options.

Please check the attached image.

[image]

Hope this helps!